# how to preform a PCoA with constraind factors

Tags: r, constraints, pca, vegan, vegdist

I have performed the following PCoA, using the following code:

```
    spe.dist <- vegdist(spe, method = "bray")
spe.braysq.pcoa <- pcoa(sqrt(spe.dist))
biplot.pcoa(spe.braysq.pcoa, sqrt(spe))
```

However, I now want to perform a constrained PCoA. I want to constrain it for the factors `field` and `moment_datacollection` and have the other factors still unconstrained. I have searched on the internet to find a way to do this. However, I could not find it. Do you guys know how to do this? Or did I set up the code the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **vegan** function `dbrda` (which is named after acronym for distance-based redundancy analysis).

Comment: thanks for your answer! If I understood it correctly: using the `dbrda` function, I have now all the factors as constrained. However I only want to have `field` and `moment_datacollection` as constrained factors, and the other 12 factors still as unconstrained. Can you explain me how to do that?

Comment: `mod <- dbrda(y ~ field + moment_datacollection, data=nameofmydataset); envfit(mod ~ ., nameofmydataset)`. The first command constraints, the second fits to the model.

Comment: Thanks, This helpt me a lot!